# ListViewitem -textview in leftside and right side i want number of contents inside particular item

Tags: android

in ListViewitem i want textview in leftend and in rightend i want number of contents inside particular item ex:i have jj,kk,ll are text in lists and contents are 3,4,5 respectively.i want in listview as jj   3,   kk   4,ll    5 in listview

Answer (score 0):

you should create a custom layout for full fill this condition in custom layout if you use Relative layout it is butter then create adapter then set adapter in listview.
I hope this is help.

Comment: Use the given link http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-2 and http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html and http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.htm